# React Native Retrieve Actual Image Sizes for React Native 0.7 / 0.71

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I would like to be able to know the actual size of a network-loaded image that has been passed into  I have tried using onLayout to work out the size (as taken from here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/858) but that seems to return the sanitised size after it's already been pushed through the layout engine.

I tried looking into onLoadStart, onLoad, onLoadEnd, onProgress to see if there was any other information available but cannot seem to get any of these to fire. I have declared them as follows: